# How to move /usr to another partition?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, mount, fstab

You can think that this question yet was asked but I wanna say that it doesn't work on my pc (ubuntu 16.04).

Here `$ sudo ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 feb 24 18:31 5ab678a9-6f9d-44bd-b549-7785220a84e2 -> ../../sda1    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 feb 24 18:31 e478047e-31f6-4ada-be12-2fe403472847 -> ../../sda5    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 feb 24 18:31 f7a7d570-9c7c-447d-9602-467e21477065 -> ../../sdb1
```

I have a ssd(sda1) and hhd(sdb1).Ubuntu located at ssd and I want move /usr to my hhd.

- **All actions which I did**:

  - **First**, I created a new usr folder on hhd `$ mkdir /media/eidan/soft/usr`
  - **Second**, I'd copied `/usr` to `/media/eidan/soft/usr` and checked content of `/media/eidan/soft/usr`.They're the same.
  - **Third**, I edited fstab.
  - `UUID=5ab678a9-6f9d-44bd-b549-7785220a84e2 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1`
  - `UUID=e478047e-31f6-4ada-be12-2fe403472847 none swap sw 0 0`
  - `UUID=f7a7d570-9c7c-447d-9602-467e21477065 /usr ext4 defaults 0 2`

After all this I rebooted my pc and ... nothing. He didn't launch ( I mean ubuntu , pc works ).What I did wrong or maybe I didn't something??

Say me step by step how to do this right

Comment: How did you copy it?

Comment: . . . and also what filesystem is on /dev/sdb1?

Comment: @Pilot6  `$ sudo cp -a /usr /media/eidan/soft/
`

Comment: @ steeldriver the same as sda1 , ext4

Comment: Possibly your error is creating the /usr directory on /media/soft: that will mean the mounted dir is `/usr/usr` I think - you need everything that was in `/usr` to be in the root of your new partition

Comment: @steeldriver can you write right `mount` command???

Comment: I don't think it's the mount command that's the problem: if `soft` is the volume label of your new drive, then you need to remove the `/media/eidan/soft/usr` directory from it and instead copy the old /usr content as `cp -a /usr/* /media/eidan/soft/` instead

Comment: @steeldriver I deleted /media/eidan/soft/usr and `$ cp -a /usr/* /media/eidan/soft/` and added this to fstab `UUID=f7a7d570-9c7c-447d-9602-467e21477065 /usr ext4 default 0 1` but nothing

Comment: @steeldriver http://imgur.com/wOhgdQW - look at this it's my sdb1